# CodeIgniter URL Function Segment as Query String

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, segment, url-mapping

Is there a way without changing the whole configuration of CodeIgniter to get the URI segment for function (`$this->uri->segment(2)`) as a regular query string instead of being directly mapped to a function?

For example, I would be forced to have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/books/functionName/bookNumber
```

I would like to have the bookNumber number right after the controller name (books):

`http://localhost/books/bookNumber` If I have the URL like this it would map the bookNumber to a function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CodeIgniter's [URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) to achieve your desired URL format.

If you add the following route to `application/config/routes.php`, then any URL that is entered that matches the route on the left, will map to the controller/function on the right:

```
$route['books/(:num)'] = "books/functionName/$1";
```

This will map a URL such as `http://localhost/books/123`, to the `functionName` function, in the `books` controller, passing `123` as the parameter.

This assumes that your 'book numbers' are always numbers (it would not work for strings), as `(:num)` will match segments only containing numbers.

Comment: Would you want to pass the query string to the function? If so, add a second parameter to the function and add this route: `$route['welcome/(:num)/(:any)'] = "welcome/functionName/$1/$2";` after the one in the answer.

Comment: I found it in the documentation, very appreciated your answer.